# How to stop artifacts occurring when zooming into a segmentation image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a bunch of segmentation images like this:
[image: Segmentation image of a human]

I'm trying to scale these images by some ratio which is calculated elsewhere in the code.

However, using the following code leads to un-wanted artifacts in the image.

```
translation_matrix = np.float32([[space_to_fill, 0, 0], [0, space_to_fill, 0)

seg_img_translation = cv2.warpAffine(seg_img_translation, translation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows), flags=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

[image: Zoomed in segmentation image of a human with artifacts]

(the screenshot has been zoomed in to focus on a particular region where these artifacts are visible).

I've tried different flags to the `warpAffine` method, but no luck there.

By the way, these images are stored as 20-channel palettes instead of RGB. Thus the image dimensions are [H x W]. The entries of this matrix correspond to [0,1,...,19]. I can convert to RGB and back, but the end result *must only* contain the original palette values.

Any thoughts on how I can zoom in on these images without introducing the artifacts?

Thanks

Comment: palette data? then you shouldn't wonder what happens when you interpolate. use INTER_NEAREST. if you don't like that, you need to put work into this situation. -- please share untouched source data. save it as a `.npy` file and upload somewhere. present a [mre].

Comment: INTER_NEAREST sorted it! I must have missed that one when trying out the different interpolation flags. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Using `cv2.INTER_NEAREST` instead of `cv2.INTER_AREA` as the `flags` parameter in `cv2.warpAffine` solved the problem.

Credit to Christoph Rackwitz for the answer.

Comment: The same solution could be used for an image with separated points (something like point cloud which was reprojected on the image). Otherwise, cv2.warpAffine loses some points, and it leads to holes between points